RelayJS: Is it possible to write tests for readInlineData?
Is it possible to write tests for readInlineData as per the test documentation? All the examples there use components.
I have tried artificially adding my function within the context of a component in the test, like this:
const environment = createMockEnvironment()

const TestQuery = graphql`
    query utilsTestQuery @relay_test_operation {
        viewer {
            article(id: "test-id") {
                ...utils_article
            }
        }
    }
`
const TestComponent = (props: any) => {

   const result = onPressRead({ //This contains readInlineData
                article: props.viewer.article,
   })
   return <>{JSON.stringify(result)}</> 
}

const renderedComponent = await waitFor(() =>
    <RelayEnvironmentProvider environment={environment}>
         <QueryRenderer
                    environment={environment}
                    query={TestQuery}
                    render={({ props }) => {
                       if (props)
                            return <TestComponent {...(props as Record<string, unknown>)}/>
                       return <Text>Loading...</Text>
                    }}
                    variables={{}}
        />
     </RelayEnvironmentProvider>
  )
)

But readInlineData data always returns undefined for my data. Has anyone figured out a way of doing this?
